# What joint should I use for this 45 degree angled brace?

Tags: joinery

What joint should I use for this 45-degree piece? It provides lateral support to a table leg, and there are two (one on each side of the upright piece in the picture). The bottom is a 3-way mortise and tenon. I'm reasonable comfortable making those now, but cutting the tenons on the 45 could be a bit challenging, especially since I'd have to do 16 of them for the whole project.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use butt joints here. Since this is part of an overall structure the joints will be strong enough in service.

You can reinforce them if you prefer*, but it shouldn't be needed if the pieces mate well, enough glue is applied and you clamp well during your glue-up.

---

*With nails or screws or dowels or biscuits or splines or Dominos or floating tenons.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Graphus that a butt joint with something mechanical would be appropriate.

However, if you wanted to do something a tiny bit more substantial, this one's easy:

[image]

It's clearly too early in the morning for me, but I can't come up with the proper name for that joint...

Comment: Looks like a housing joint to me.

Comment: Note in particular, that the cutout at the bottom is horizontal, but the cutout at the top slopes.

Comment: @MartinBonner Nice catch

Comment: Yup, different slopes because I'm somewhat lazy. I cut the top 45 with a circular saw (that had a 90 degree guide to ensure square without any saw marks), and I blunted the bottom of the bracket so I wouldn't have to do any fussy undercutting at the post. I can't for the life of me remember how I cut that end blunt (router, circular saw or miter saw), but if I had to do it again, I'd probably lean toward the miter saw at 45 degrees. (Though I think I had problems getting 5.5" cut in one pass...)